# Programatically select rows in a grid in MouseDown gets reset during MouseUp/MouseClick

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I've got a MouseDown event on my GridView:

```
    private void gdcSVNDefaultView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var vw = (GridView)sender;
        var hitInfo = vw.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);

        DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = SelectChildRows(hitInfo.RowHandle, vw);
    }

    private static bool SelectChildRows(int r, GridView view)
    {
        if (!view.IsGroupRow(r) || !view.GetRowExpanded(r))
            return false;

        var childRowCount = view.GetChildRowCount(r);
        var first = view.GetChildRowHandle(r, 0);
        var last = (first + childRowCount - 1);

        view.SelectRange(first, last);
        return true;
    }
```

Screenshot of my form since not everyone is familiar with the DevExpress grids and might not know what i mean by a 'Group':
[image]

When you have a Group in the grid and click on that Group row instead of an actual 'data' row, I want to select all the child rows belonging to that Group.

The code works. If I click on a Group (for example, `Type: Warning` in my screenshot) and hold the mouse down I can see it select all the child rows... But as soon as I let up on the mouse, it de-selects them and selects *just* the group row. So if you just click quickly, like you normally would, you see them all flash quickly as as their selected state toggles.

Unfortunately, the Mouse events don't have any sort of "Handled" property I can set to make the MouseUp / Click not fire. I tried moving the code in my MouseDown to the MouseUp event and it doesn't even temporarily select everything. DX also has a "RowClick" event, tried it there... same results as the MouseUp.

Any ideas on how I can "cancel" those events?

Edit: Turns out there **is** a `Handled` property if you cast the MouseEventArgs to a DXMouseEventArgs object... But it still observes the same behavior.

Comment: I guess that anyone who can answer this question **should** have at least `DevExpress` installed to try and find the solution. Otherwise we may just think of some suggestion. Sometimes, third-party controls can hardly be customized and can make you confused with some strange behavior (after customized).

Comment: Unfortunately, yea, it is tough to troubleshoot without DevExpress installed but it is quite popular so I thought I'd tag it and try here. The official support hasn't been able to help much either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I found out that I need to set `Handled` in both the MouseDown **and** MouseUp events in order to get the behavior desired:

```
public class MyForm
{
  private bool _b;

    private void gdcSVNDefaultView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        var vw = (GridView)sender;
        var hitInfo = vw.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);

        if (hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.RowGroupButton)
            return;

        _b = false;
        if (vw.IsGroupRow(hitInfo.RowHandle))
            _b = SelectChildRows(hitInfo.RowHandle, vw);

        DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = _b;
    }

    private void gdcSVNDefaultView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = _b;
    }

    private static bool SelectChildRows(int r, GridView view)
    {
        if (!view.GetRowExpanded((r)))
            return false;

        if (ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift && ModifierKeys != Keys.Control)
            view.ClearSelection();

        var childRowCount = view.GetChildRowCount(r);
        var first = view.GetChildRowHandle(r, 0);
        var last = (first + childRowCount - 1);

        view.SelectRange(first, last);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: This `IF` block is NOT required for the core functionality. I found that if I click on multiple Groups it was adding that Range to the current Selection, which might be unexpected behavior for the end user. I added a check to see if the user is holding down the Control or Shift keys when they click the Group row. If not, then clear the current selection and select the new range

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Click` event instead of `MouseDown`? Might be worth a shot. From [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_MouseUptopic):

> Note that the Click event also fires after the mouse button has been released. The difference is that the Click event is only raised if the mouse pointer is within the View when releasing the mouse button.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to determine which row was clicked in the regular `Click` event. If multi select wasn't enabled, then it'd be easy, but since they **can** select multiple rows I cannot figure out how to determine what row it is.